# Oracle apex report does not get printed when I click the button but gets printed when I test It from shared components

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, bi-publisher

I am trying to use BI publisher as the printing server on my APEX app, but when I try to use the generated link (f?p=&APP_ID.:0:&SESSION.:PRINT_REPORT=COUNTRY%20INFO) on a button it does not work and gives a error as "Contact your application administrator. Details about this incident are available via debug id "4162"." but the debug log doesn't show any errors, however the report gets printed fine when i click the test report button in "Shared Components/Report Queries/Edit" tab.
I can't find the mistake here

I use oracle apex 22.0 on Oracle 21c xe locally, BI publisher server is also setup locally

I tried the link with different buttons in different pages but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured your Report Printing Parameters in APEX. You'll need Admin credentials. Login to APEX Admin Services application. See this document for details on how to log into the Admin Services application: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e12512/adm_login.htm#CHDHCIFG

This Blogspot post details the settings you'll need to set and where you can find them in the Admin Services app: https://oraclemasterminds.blogspot.com/2014/10/configuring-apex-to-use-bi-publisher.html

Depending on how you have things set up, these may be the only steps you need to take to resolve the printing issue. A lot of printing issues with BI Publisher in APEX have to do with how the two are linked together.